# How to let react native <Text> recognize Icon characters which are set as String type

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am in a react native project using Iconfont characters.

I set a object like this:

```
rowData = {iconCode: '&#xe655;'}
```

I want to put iconCode into `<Text>{rowData.iconCode}</Text>`. But after rendered, the result is `<Text>'&#xe655;'</Text>`. So how can I turn String type `'&#xe655;'` into plain characters &#xe655; like `<Text>&#xe655;</Text>`?

React Native doesn't support document, so I can't use innerHtml to do this. Any solution by React Native language?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

`rowData = {iconCode: 'xe655'}
<Text>{String.fromCharCode('0' + rowData.iconCode)}</Text>`